# Implement a .vbs in a batch without it being stored locally

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I would make this short & sweet, but I'd like to explain what/why I need help with. I have been working on a batch file that collects various information files from a system that are helpful in debugging situations. As a kernel debugger, having to ask for crash dumps, sysinfo logs, all the nine yards, over and over again, is very tiresome. With this said, I am working on a pre-existing batch file that collects such files.

I have updated it as requested by the original creator in various ways, however, their one request is one I am not sure how to go about. On Windows 8/8.1, you have the option of logging into a Microsoft account. If you use this method of logging into Windows 8, upon the completion of this batch, it will display your email address in the logs. Given this is a popular collection application among the BSOD community, the creator has received various 'complaints', all of which valid, that this is a security issue. With that said, a .vbs script has been created that essentially removes the line in the log that denotes **'Registered Owner'**.

The creator wants to implement this .vbs script *into* the batch file in such a way that the script is created FROM the batch in %temp%, run successfully as needed, and then afterwards deleted. I do not know how to implement it this way, which is my problem. I of course successfully made a simple example \Data folder within the batch directory in which I stored the script, and *then* called it from the batch. However, as far as creating the script from within the batch itself within %temp% goes without having it existing locally beforehand, I have no idea.

I would very much appreciate some guidance/what to read to figure this out.

Regards,

Patrick

Comment: Is the vbs-script a fixed text or are there some variable parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier is to use batch to do it.

```
findstr /i /v /c:"Registered Owner" c:\windows\minidump\somelogfile.txt >c:\windows\somefilewithoutregisteredowner.txt
```

For help

```
findstr/?
```

To extract a vbs from bat

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=6 delims=" %%i IN (%0) DO @echo %%i >>"%temp%\tmp010.vbs"
cscript "%temp%\tmp010.vbs"
del "%temp%\tmp010.vbs"
pause

goto :eof
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    ie.AddressBar = 0 
    ie.Visible = 1 
    ie.ToolBar = 0 
    ie.StatusBar = 0 
    ie.Left = 400 
    ie.Top = 100 
    ie.Width = 800 
    ie.Height = 900 
    ie.Navigate2 "http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista?tab=question&status=all"
```

Remember help is available on every command.

Comment: I have edited:

'findstr /i /v /c:"Registered Owner" c:\windows\minidump\somelogfile.txt >c:\windows\somefilewithoutregisteredowner.txt'

to

'findstr /i /v /%HomeDrive%"Registered Owner" %HomeDrive%\%HomePath%\Documents\SysnativeForumsFileCollectionApp\systeminfo1.txt >%HomeDrive%\%HomePath%\Documents\SysnativeForumsFileCollectionApp\systeminfo.txt'

It generates a systeminfo.txt file from systeminfo1.txt, however, it goes too fast therefore no information is written to the systeminfo.txt. I tried adding:

'timeout /t 15 /nobreak >NUL'

after but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It can't go too fast. In my code the `/c:"Registered Owner"` means `/c` search literally (rather than regular expressions) and `:` seperates the switch from the parameters, and `"Registered Owner"` is the term being searched for (enclosed in quotes because it contains spaces). `/c:"anything"` is not referring to a drive but a findstr switch.

Comment: To indicate regular expression or literal, `/r` and `/l` are used. Search string can be directly included in the command without any switch, `/c` is required when the term to search includes spaces. `findstr "this text" ...` will match any line containing `this` or `text`, but `findstr /c:"this text" ...` will match lines containing `this text`.